# How to move a span (or div) manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the code I am using. I am able to accomplish the task of showing image under the link, but I am not able drag it. The script accomplishes the task of showing the image span on one click and closing it in the second click. What I want is showing them on one click and draggable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();


    $('.show_hide').click(function () {
        var el = $(this);
        var slidingDiv = el.find("span.slidingDiv");
        $(".slidingDiv" ).draggable();

        if (slidingDiv.length > 0) {
            slidingDiv.slideToggle(function () { el.after(slidingDiv); });
        }
        else {
            slidingDiv = el.next("span.slidingDiv");
            el.append(slidingDiv);
            slidingDiv.slideToggle();
        }
        return false;
    });
    $('.show_hide_close').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent("a.show_hide").click();
        return false;
    });
});

 $(function() {
        $( ".slidingDiv" ).draggable();
    });

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#" class="show_hide" style="position: relative;">Japan</a><span class="slidingDiv"><img src="02-1 ImageFiles/01 Japan.JPG" style="width:235px; height:245px;" /><a href="#" class="show_hide_close">Close</a></span> is made up of islands,
```

Comment: This appears to be the same question you asked earlier (which was closed) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144968/how-to-manually-move-an-image-in-a-web-page

Comment: Are you including the jQueryUI javascript file? .draggable() is a jQueryUI function.

Comment: @KevinBoucher Yes. I added more explanation.

Comment: @Zappa Yes. I added the following: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: `$(".slidingDiv" ).draggable();` is this a typo? Did you mean `slidingDiv.draggable()` ?

Comment: @ithcy slidingDiv is a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following examples,

for simple:
[Link1](http://jsfiddle.net/uPRaH/)
code:

```
$(".selector").draggable({
    cancel: "button"
});​
```

for some more: [Link2](http://jsfiddle.net/uPRaH/1/)  [Link3](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/EPKfR/)

for deep: [Link4](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QWgRF/)